# Sql Multiple Conditions Method

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, query-optimization

I've been trying to find a way of using multiple conditions with Sql, at the moment I am using Entity Framework. There is a very good chance that this is the only way to achieve what I want but I wondered if anyone knew a more efficient method.

Essentially I am using criteria to find the next row in the database which should be picked. For example lets use the 2 following conditions:

1) Field1 = A;

2) Field2 = B;

So in the following table:

```
| RowId | Field1 | Field2 |

| 0001  |     A     |  B |

| 0002   | B | B |

| 0003 | C | C |

| 0004 | A | C |
```

I need to pick each row individually in the following order:

```
0001 - Both Condtions Satisfied,

0004 - Condition 1 Satisfied,

0002 - Condition 2 Satisfied,

0003 - No conditions satisfied
```

At the moment I am doing the following

```
public TestObj GetNextObj()
{
    using (TestDb testDb = new TestDb())
    {
        TestObj testObj = (from o in testDb.TestTable
                           where o.Field1 == A && o.Field2 == B
                           select o).FirstOrDefault();

        if (testObj != null)
           return testObj;

        testObj = (from o in testDb.TestTable
                           where o.Field1 == A
                           select o).FirstOrDefault();

        if (testObj != null)
           return testObj;

        testObj = (from o in testDb.TestTable
                           where o.Field2 == B
                           select o).FirstOrDefault();

        if (testObj != null)
           return testObj;

        testObj = (from o in testDb.TestTable
                           select o).FirstOrDefault();

         return testObj;
    }
}
```

This works okay, however I want to allow the conditions to be defined in a table and I am worried that when the number of conditions increases that this process will begin taking a very long time.

Is there another way to do what I am attempting here??

Thanks.

EDIT:::::

Now using the following code to select items from a table in order as defined by another table::

```
public static SortTest GetRow()
    {
        using (TestDb testDb = new TestDb())
        {
            SortParam[] sortParams = (from sp in testDb.SortParams
                                      orderby sp.Priority ascending
                                      select sp).ToArray();

            if (sortParams.Length == 0)
            {
                SortTest sortTest = (from st in testDb.SortTests
                                     orderby st.RowId ascending 
                                     select st).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine("Short route");
                return sortTest;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Long route");

            StringBuilder sqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            sqlQueryBuilder.Append("SELECT * FROM [Proto].[dbo].[SortTests] ORDER BY \n");

            foreach (SortParam sortParam in sortParams)
            {
                sqlQueryBuilder.Append("CASE WHEN " + sortParam.FieldName + " LIKE '%" + sortParam.FieldValue + "%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,\n");
            }

            sqlQueryBuilder.Append("\nRowId"); //By default use row Id
            DbSqlQuery<SortTest> dbSqlQuery = testDb.SortTests.SqlQuery(sqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
            return dbSqlQuery.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

I may have to alter thigns to prevent Sql Injection, but this works for now.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple way of doing it in a single query in SQL:

```
select *
from o
order by case Field1 when 'A' then 1 else 2 end,
         case Field2 when 'B' then 1 else 2 end,
         RowId
```

Comment: Your suggestion is fine! One could also use something like 'decode' or write a function that returns 1/2 if the values are more complex than just 'A', 'B', 'C'

Comment: @AKDADEVIL: decode is specific to Oracle - I think the OP may be using SQLServer, based on his tags on other questions.

Comment: You're probably right. Well, since I already upvoted your answer I'm not feeling guilty in any way... ;)

Comment: Thanks that does work great. Is there anyway to use something like this: ...CASE Field1 LIKE 'A%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END...

Comment: Sorry, just got it I am now using:  ...CASE WHEN Field1 LIKE 'A%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, ...